# Login page in android using database

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and Java. I'm doing a login page program. In that program I don't know how to do user authentication or validation process.

please help me

```
public class demo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 EditText txtbox1, txtbox2;
 private DataHelper dh;
 Button button2, button1;
 String name1, name2, name;
 String DB_PATH, DATABASE_NAME;
 String unames;
 TextView tv;
 private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
  private DataHelper db;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  txtbox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
  txtbox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
  button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
  button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
  button1.setOnClickListener(this);
  button2.setOnClickListener(this);
  tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);  
        tv.setSelected(true); 
 }

@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int i = v.getId();
  {
   if (i == R.id.Button01) {
    name1 = txtbox1.getText().toString();
    name2 = txtbox2.getText().toString();

    System.out.println("txtbox1" + txtbox1);
    System.out.println("name1" + name1);
    System.out.println("name2" + name2);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Insert Employee Details:\n");
      dh = new DataHelper(this);
          dh.deleteAll();
    dh.insert(name1);
    dh.insert(name2);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name1,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    List<String> names = this.dh.selectAll();
    /* sb.append("Names in database:\n"); */
    for (String name : names) {
     sb.append(name + "\n");
     System.out.println("name=" + names);

     Log.d("EXAMPLE", "names size - " + names.size());
    }

   }
  }
  if (i == R.id.Button02)
  System.out.println("ok");
  System.out.println("name=" + unames);

/*     GetValue();
*/
  {
   if (name1.equals(unames)) {
    System.out.println("ok1");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name1,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else {
    System.out.println("no");
    /*
     * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),no ,
     * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     */

   }

  }

 }
}
```

database part

```
public class DataHelper {

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "example1rrrr.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
 private static final String name = "name";
 private static final String password = "password";
 private static final String KEY_ROWID = "rowid";
 private Context context;
 private static SQLiteDatabase db;


 private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
 private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME
   + "(name) values (?)";

 public DataHelper(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
  OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
  this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
 }

 public long insert(String name) {
  this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
  return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
 }


public void deleteAll() {
  this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
 }

 public List<String> selectAll() {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name" },
    null, null, null, null, "name asc");
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
    list.add(cursor.getString(0));
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
   cursor.close();
  }
  return list;
 }

 private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  OpenHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
     + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   Log.w("Example",
     "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
   onCreate(db);

  }
```

Comment: I guess it will depend on what you are trying to login to.

Comment: im using two button sign up and sign in if im pressing sign up  input data ll stored in database another button signin pressed  authentication or validation process ll do.. so my question is how to authentication after pressing signin pll tell me ..i dont know .the query

Comment: Is this just a local authentication rather than say a network authentication?

Comment: pl help im trying past 3weeks pl

Comment: put errorlog or stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you're using a db? It would be easier to just store the login data in shared preferences:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: actually the data storing in database but i don know how to access from database and authentication ...pl helllp me